# Open source proxy server usable through a website with user login

Tags: linux, open-source, web-apps, self-hosted, proxy

I want to set up a proxy server where I can log in on a webpage, type in the URL into an input box and surf to websites and modern webapps. Similar to [hide.me proxy website](https://hide.me/).

Is there something open source and easy to set up around for a Linux webserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to run a CGI Proxy.  There are several round, php-based an otherwise, such as [Glype](https://www.glype.com/), or various alternatives such as.

[PHP Web Proxy](https://sourceforge.net/projects/php-proxy/)

Disclaimer: I work for Qbik who are the authors of [WinGate Proxy Server](http://www.wingate.com)